# Run line in Python terminal not working after Run file in terminal. Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-code

I just started using VSC. I have created a .py file with the line `print('Hola mundo')`. When I run the line (Mayus+Intro in Linux at least), it works fine.

`>>> print('Hola mundo') Hola mundo`

But then I try to Run the file (with the play button), and this errors raises:

```
>>> /home/tidop/anaconda3/envs/snappy/bin/python /home/tidop/Documentos/vs_folder/Hello_World.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    /home/tidop/anaconda3/envs/snappy/bin/python /home/tidop/Documentos/vs_folder/Hello_World.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have enter `exit()` in that terminal, so a normal linux terminal is used now. Here, I use the Run file button without problems.

`(snappy) tidop@tidop-System-Product-Name:~/Documentos/vs_folder$ /home/tidop/anaconda3/envs/snappy/bin/python /home/tidop/Documentos/vs_folder/Hello_World.py Hola mundo`

But now I can't run just a line in here, cause it causes a bash error.

Question: How can I run indifferently lines and files in VSC?

I use Spyder and this problem does not exist...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

This comment under the answer addresses the OP's question.

If you mean directly run a line or lines in the script file instead of typing code in the terminal. Right mouse button --> `Run Selection/Line in Interactive Window`, this opens an interactive window to run the selected portion of code. Here is a [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffDVs.gif). As you can see, there is a conflict between the shortcut keys. If you want to use shortcut keys, please delete other commands bound by `Shift + Enter` first, or change new shortcut keys for `Run Selection/Line in Interactive Window`.

---

You need to distinguish two concepts: the **system terminal** and the **python interactive terminal**.

The integrated terminal in vscode uses the system terminal. When you type `python` or `py` in the terminal, this is a command that will make the system terminal open the python interactive terminal.

[image]

In the python interactive terminal, you can directly type python code and run it.

[image]

But if you type a system command, such as `C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe c:/WorkSpace/pytest11/demo4.py`, which is the command for vscode to run the python script (that is, the command for you to click the play button to run the code), then the python interactive terminal will report an error. Since this is not python code it tells you syntax error.

[image]

If you want to use both at the same time, you just need to open both integrated terminals at the same time.

[image]

Comment: Even with the two kind of terminals opened, when I Run the file, VSC uses the interactive one, giving the error. It does not know how to choose the correct one.

Comment: You need to run the script once, then open an interactive terminal by typing python in a new terminal.

Comment: If you open an interactive terminal in the terminal where the script command was executed, vscode will not recognize its changes. When you press the play button again to run the script, it will still run the script in the terminal where the command was last executed (the one where you just typed python to open the interactive terminal).

Comment: It seems to not work neither. I run the script, then open an interactive terminal, but line runs in the first terminal... VSC seems to not know how to deal with this?

Comment: Ok, please follow the steps below. First delete all existing terminals, then click the play button to select `Run Python File` to run the code in the terminal. Then create a new terminal and type `python` in this new terminal to open an interactive terminal. Now you have two terminals, one to execute commands (powershell) and one to type python code directly and run it. I just made a [gif](https://imgur.com/C6O8qWQ.gif) for your reference.

Comment: If you mean directly run a line or lines in the script file instead of typing code in the terminal. Right mouse button --> `Run Selection/Line in Interactive Window`, this opens an interactive window to run the selected portion of code. Here is a [GIF](https://i.imgur.com/jNc0VGJ.gif). As you can see, there is a conflict between the shortcut keys. If you want to use shortcut keys, please delete other commands bound by `Shift + Enter` first, or change new shortcut keys for `Run Selection/Line in Interactive Window`.

Comment: this second comment is the answer to my question, thanks. I need to change the shortcuts. How do I mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: I'll update the answer to write the comment into the answer.